# Write data in property file using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
package com.igate.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;



public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestController() {

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


                response.setContentType("text/html");

        String action= request.getParameter("action");


        System.out.println(action);




    if(action.equals("proceed"))

    {

        String pf =request.getParameter("pf");
        String app =request.getParameter("app");
        String bw =request.getParameter("b");


        PropertiesConfiguration config =null;

        try {
            config = new PropertiesConfiguration("D:/SCT_WRK/projectOne/framework.properties");
            config.setProperty("PLATFORM",pf);
            config.setProperty("APP_TYPE",app);
            config.setProperty("BROWSER",bw);

            config.save();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }





    }



    }

    }
```

Actually

```
I  want to write data in property file that data comes from jsp file(user entered data). but above code is not working.
```

I need -
1>. write user input data in property file without effecting previous data of property file.

but  It is giving some problem-

1>.  EXCEPTION: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.igate.controller.TestController
2>. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
3>. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException

and this is complete stack trace.

Here is full stack trace..
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.igate.controller.TestController
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknow Source)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1672)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apache Tomcat/7.0.4
```

Comment: I had tried to place my property file in src code OR  WEB INF/Classes but it not working from anywhere.

please guys suggest me ?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. The container is unable to locate the class `ConfigurationException`  from the `org.apache.commons.configuration` package at run-time. Make sure you did not misplace the required dependencies.

Comment: yeah ,I placed all jar the files in WEBINF/classes .. now it's Working.. !

thank you Tiny

Answer (score 0):

This is the jar issue,

http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

and copy to your lib folder.
clean the project and tomcat.
restart the server and try.